# XCode 7.3 Splash screen Localization

Tags: iphone, ipad, xcode7, splash-screen, launch-screen

How do i add splash screen for multiple languages that is based on users language of the phone ? That is if the user is danish then a danish splash screen if the user is english then english splash screen.

The project that i build is an output from the cordova ionic build that is once i build to remotely i open the xcode.proj file  [image]
For multiple languages how to i set up localized resource launch images in the build .

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue?

Comment: No, we just kept to the default. So common ones for all languages.

Answer (score -1):

After enabling localization in the Project:

- Localize your .xcAsset icons

than localize texts by:

1.

[image]

2.

[image]

3.

[image]